# Is there a way to unset a FatFree variable inside a view template?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, fat-free-framework

I am aware you can set a F3 variable by using `<set name="John" />` but I'm wondering if there is something like `<unset foo />`. I want to be able to do this inside a view template. I've looked all over the Internet but yet to find anything...

Answer (score 1):

There's no such `<unset>` directive. But you can achieve the same using one of the two following options:

- `<set foo="{{NULL}}"/>`
- `{~ unset($foo) ~}`